# Can I use a variable instead of the integer in OVER clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a query that calculates a 50 day moving average from a column Price like this:

```
select Date,  
       price, 
       avg(price) over( order by Date, Date rows between 50 preceding and current row) as moving_avg 
from t1
```

Now I would like to replace the integer 50 by a integer variable to do a loop testing different moving average length.

When I try I get:

> Incorrect syntax near '@MA'

Comment: I'm not certain on the answer since I haven't run into this before, but it seems like this would be similar to [using a variable for TOP in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927450/use-variable-with-top-in-select-statement-in-sql-server-without-making-it-dynami). In order to do that you have to put the variable in parantheses. Maybe try `rows between (@MA) preceding and current row` and see if that makes it happy. </stab_in_the_dark>

Comment: @JNevill Good thinking but I just tried `(50) and (@MA) ` and it definitely doesn't like parenthesis in either case

Comment: Shucks. Sounds like you'll have to go with dynamic sql then. That's always a party pooper :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping that (Select @MA) would work, but alas no luck

Perhaps you can go dynamic

```
Declare @MA int = 50

Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='Select Date, price, avg(price) over( order by Date, Date rows between '+cast(@MA as varchar(25))+' preceding and current row) as moving_avg from t1 '
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: @Rich Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. If you know how to read them, the syntax diagrams included in the SQL documentation are quite thorough.

As you peruse the one for [`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx#Anchor_0), you'll eventually find that the variant for the `PRECEDING` specification is `<unsigned_value_specification> PRECEDING`.

And then lower down:

```
<unsigned value specification> ::=   
{  <unsigned integer literal> }
```

So, unfortunately, your only choice at this time is to use a *literal* - not a variable, not an expression. When variants (variable vs literal, say) are allowed, the syntax diagrams do tend to make such variants explicitly visible.

---

The comparable syntax for [`TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) has:

```
[   
    TOP (expression) [PERCENT]  
    [ WITH TIES ]  
]
```

where as you already know, you can use any expression here.